# TreeTableView add nested value to TreeItemPropertyValueFactory

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I need to add to my TreeTableView the content for two columns("Id" and "Workplace").
I don't know how to do it, because I can't get nested value from Manager -> ArrayList.
What should I pass in TreeItemPropertyValueFactory if the type of the content can be only String???

The rest of code works OK.
I will be grateful for any help.

[image]
[image]

```
public void showStaffInTreeTable(){
        Employee emp_1 = new Employee("1", "secretary");
        Employee emp_2 = new Employee("2", "cleaner");
        Employee emp_3 = new Employee("3", "driver");
        Employee emp_4 = new Employee("4", "mechanic");

        ArrayList<Employee> johnStaff = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(emp_1, emp_2));
        ArrayList<Employee> amandaStaff = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(emp_3, emp_4));

        Manager john = new Manager("John", johnStaff);
        Manager amanda = new Manager("Amanda", amandaStaff);

        TreeTableColumn<Manager, String> columnManager = new TreeTableColumn<>("Manager");
        TreeTableColumn<Manager, String> columnStaffId = new TreeTableColumn<>("Id");
        TreeTableColumn<Manager, String> columnStaffWorkplace = new TreeTableColumn<>("Workplace");

        columnManager.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("managersName"));
        columnStaffId.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>
                ("how to pass here: Manager-> ArrayList<Employess> -> getEmployee -> getId???"));
        columnStaffWorkplace.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>
                ("how to pass here: Manager-> ArrayList<Employess> -> getEmployee -> getWorkplace???"));

        TreeTableView<Manager> managers = new TreeTableView<>();
        managers.getColumns().addAll(columnManager, columnStaffId, columnStaffWorkplace);

        TreeItem managerItem_1 = new TreeItem(john);
        managerItem_1.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(emp_1), new TreeItem<>(emp_2));
        TreeItem managerItem_2 = new TreeItem(amanda);
        managerItem_2.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(emp_3), new TreeItem<>(emp_4));

        TreeItem root = new TreeItem(new Manager("", new ArrayList<>()));
        root.getChildren().addAll(managerItem_1, managerItem_2);
        root.setExpanded(true);

        managers.setRoot(root);
    }
```

```
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String workplace;

    public Employee(String id, String workplace) {
        this.id = id;
        this.workplace = workplace;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWorkplace() {
        return workplace;
    }

    public void setWorkplace(String workplace) {
        this.workplace = workplace;
    }
}
```

```
public class Manager {
    private String managersName;
    private List<Employee> managersStaff = new ArrayList<>();

    public Manager(String managersName, List<Employee> managersStaff) {
        this.managersName = managersName;
        this.managersStaff = managersStaff;
    }

    public String getManagersName() {
        return managersName;
    }

    public void setManagersName(String managersName) {
        this.managersName = managersName;
    }

    public List<Employee> getManagersStaff() {
        return managersStaff;
    }

    public void setManagersStaff(List<Employee> managersStaff) {
        this.managersStaff = managersStaff;
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't post screenshots of text ..

Comment: ok, but how to mark in code than which line contains  exactly my problem?? Lines are not numbered and the whole code is below screenshot.

Comment: add a comment to the code, something like `//>>>>> here is the important part`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
columnStaffId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    TreeItem<?> item = cellData.getValue();
    Object data = item.getValue();
    if (data instanceof Employee) {
        Employee employee = (Employee)data ;
        return new SimpleStringProperty(employee.getId());
    } else {
        return new SimpleStringProperty("");
    }
});
```

Note in Java 14 you can simplify this to

```
columnStaffId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    if (cellData.getValue().getValue() instanceof Employee employee) {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(employee.getId());
    } else {
        return new SimpleStringProperty("");
    }
});
```

Your setup is a little weird, as you declare a `TreeTableView<Manager>` but some of the items don't contain `Manager`s, but `Employee`s. So there's no real guarantee you don't get `ClassCastException`s thrown in places here, or other errors caused by the `TreeItemPropertyValueFactory` trying to call `getManagersName()` on an object that isn't a `Manager`.

You might want to refactor so you use a `TreeTableView<Object>`, or maybe refactor the model so that `Manager` and `Employee` are both subclasses of some other class (which you then use as the type for your `TreeTableView`).

Comment: thanks a lot! It works as I wished. I just wanted to avoid creating next class with collecting fields from two other clessess. But if see any problems will do it. For  now works like a charm!